# How to type the MongoDB projection results

Tags: typescript, mongodb

When I query with projections then I expect the type to be different. For example, my collection has documents of type User.

```
interface User {
    _id?: ObjectId
    username: string
    foo: number
}
```

And when I query it, then I expect the result to be of type UserView

```
interface UserView {
    _id: ObjectId
    username: string
}
```

My Repository looks something like this.

```
class UserRepository {
    private collection: Collection<User>
    
    constructor(db: Db) {
        this.collection = db.collection<User>('User')
    }

    public async getUserById(id: ObjectId): Promise<UserView | null> {
        // Result has type User
        const result = await this.collection
            .findOne({ _id: ${ eq: id } }, { projection: { _id: 1, username: 1 })
    }
}
```

Current solutions I can think of is that I create a new collection with each type like this.

```
this.collection = db.collection<User>('User')
this.viewCollection = db.collection<UserView>('User')
```

or leave the typing out and return the function like this:

```
    public async getUserById(id: ObjectId): Promise<UserView | null> {
        // Result has type Document
        const result = await this.collection
            .findOne({ _id: ${ eq: id } }, { projection: { _id: 1, username: 1 })
        if (result) return result as Userview
        return null
    }
```

What's the best approach to have proper typing in my MongoDB queries with projections?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all you don't need to create custom types for every combination of projections you may be using. Instead of declaring `UserView` you can use the builtin Pick utility type: `Pick<User,'_id'|'username'>`.

Then as for the type-safe retrieval of the user projection itself, instead of the more error-prone type casting with `as`, you can take full advantage of Generics with type argument inference and the `keyof` operator to reach something like this:

```
public async getUserById<Field extends keyof User>(
    id: mongodb.ObjectId,
    fields: Field[]
): Promise<Pick<User, Field> | null> {   
    const projection: mongodb.FindOptions['projection'] = {};
    fields.forEach((field) => { projection[field] = 1; });
    const result = await this.db.collection<User>('users').findOne(
      { _id: id },
      { projection }
    );
    return result;
}

// Usage:
const user = await this.getUserById('myId', ['_id', 'username']);
console.log(user); // user is fully type-safe with only the _id and username fields
```

### Long explanation:

I reached the previous solution iteratively, you can see my progress with the various versions of `getUserById` methods bellow, it may be useful if you want to understand it better:

```
import * as mongodb from 'mongodb';

interface User {
  _id: string,
  username: string,
  foo: string
}

export default abstract class Test {

  private static db: mongodb.Db;

  public static async init() {
    const client = new mongodb.MongoClient('YOUR_MONGO_URL');
    await client.connect();
    this.db = client.db();
  }

  public static async test() {
    const user: User = { _id: 'myId', username: 'chris', foo: 'bar' };
    console.log(user);

    // Iteration 1: Using hardcoded union type and projection (not reusable)
    const user1 = await this.getUserById1('myId');
    console.log(user1);

    // Iteration 2: Using hardcoded projection (not reusable)
    const user2 = await this.getUserById2<'_id' | 'username'>('myId');
    console.log(user2);

    // Interation 3: Using dynamic union type and projection, but duplicated (not ideal) 
    const user3 = await this.getUserById3<'_id' | 'username'>('myId', ['_id', 'username']);
    console.log(user3);

    // Iteration 4: Using dynamic projection with generic type argument inference, the best solution!
    const user4 = await this.getUserById4('myId', ['_id', 'username']);
    console.log(user4);
  }

  // Iteration 1: Using hardcoded union type and projection (not reusable)
  public static async getUserById1(
    id: string
  ): Promise<Pick<User, '_id' | 'username'> | null> {
    const result = await this.db.collection<User>('users').findOne(
      { _id: id },
      { projection: { _id: true, username: true } }
    );
    return result;
  }

  // Iteration 2: Using hardcoded projection (not reusable)
  public static async getUserById2<Field extends keyof User>(
    id: string
  ): Promise<Pick<User, Field> | null> {
    const result = await this.db.collection<User>('users').findOne(
      { _id: id },
      { projection: { _id: true, username: true } }
    );
    return result;
  }

  // Interation 3: Using dynamic union type and projection, but duplicated (not ideal) 
  public static async getUserById3<Field extends keyof User>(
    id: string,
    fields: (keyof User)[]
  ): Promise<Pick<User, Field> | null> {   
    const projection: mongodb.FindOptions['projection'] = {};
    fields.forEach((field) => { projection[field] = true; });
    const result = await this.db.collection<User>('users').findOne(
      { _id: id },
      { projection }
    );
    return result;
  }

  // Iteration 4: Using dynamic projection with generic type argument inference, the best solution!
  public static async getUserById4<Field extends keyof User>(
    id: string,
    fields: Field[]
  ): Promise<Pick<User, Field> | null> {   
    const projection: mongodb.FindOptions['projection'] = {};
    fields.forEach((field) => { projection[field] = true; });
    const result = await this.db.collection<User>('users').findOne(
      { _id: id },
      { projection }
    );
    return result;
  }

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation. I really appreciate your take and will try to incorporate it into my solutions.

Comment: Important typescript lesson here!
Helped me a lot!